# Python: subprocess output pipe not updating in long running process

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to set up a python process that listens on a port and kicks off a curl command whenever a client connects, giving the results of the curl to the client.

I set up the following script, but results given to the client (`output1+output2`) never changes after the first run of `curl`. The results should be changing because the curl command itself is returning different results each time.

I'm not sure what's going on. Either the curl is only being run once and never again. Or the pipe is not getting flushed?

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess
import os

cmd1 = "curl -m 15 -s http://cluster.xxxxx.com:8080/suggestions | jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv'"
ps1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output1 = ps1.communicate()[0]

cmd2="curl -m 15 -s http://localhost:8080/directories?sum=diskspaceConsumed | jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @tsv'| grep -v 'dt='| sed 's/^/HDFSdiskspaceConsumed{hdfs_dir=\"/; s/\t/\"}\t/'"
ps2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,bufsize=0)
output2 = ps2.communicate()[0]

output = output1+output2
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/metrics/")
def home():
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Yes, your `curl` commands are only run once, when starting your server. Then you return the same stored `output` data every time. You need to run your subprocesses within the `home` function for them to update. Note, however, that it will lead to longer response times.

Comment: That explains it. I'm going to try moving it into `home` now, as you suggested. Is there a better way to do this to avoid longer response times?

Comment: It depends on whether you must have new and the very latest data for every call. If you need that, there is no way around it. Otherwise you might be able to define a background task that fetches new data every once in a while and caches it for when your page is accessed.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. If push comes to shove, I'll do that, but for now I don't think it'll be an issue, we only have one or two clients hitting that service every couple minutes. Thanks for your help on this. So, there's no way to streamline long-running processes in python? Or is it Flask that's the bottleneck?